# Can I set up multiple accounts on DD-WRT?

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, authentication

I want to set up multiple accounts on DD-WRT (accounts meaning, username-password pairs). Specifically, I want one to be used primarily for remote web management (though there is no reason to restrict the account). Is this possible? If so, how do I go about it?

I'm running:

```
Router Model TP-Link TL-WR1043ND
Firmware Version DD-WRT v24-sp2 (08/07/10) std - build 14896
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I can find, it does not currently support different logins for different purposes.
<sup><sup>[[1]](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Web_Interface#Setting_details_about_the_Web-GUI)</sup></sup>

Also, not that all the documentation specifically talks of [*the* default username/password](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Index:FAQ#What.27s_the_default_username_and_password.3F), implying that there is only a single login (at least in regards to making changes).

Since it is an open-source firmware with an active community of developers constantly making changes, your best bet is to [request the feature](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=855a5fc9f23154e83a558386ede21303) on the forums.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a standard `/etc/password` file.  However, you likely don't have tools to add new users.  Carefully add a new record to this file.  (Back it up, and don't logoff until you are sure the new file is working.) You could do this with an editor by copying and editing an existing record like `nobody`.

Assuming your new user is `webadmin`, you should be able to set a password for it with the command `passwd webadmin`.

Comment: The "password" file is /etc/passwd not /etc/password. I wouldn't advise a newbie to edit this file either (if they're asking this question, it's a sign they are not Linux veterans, and may make an unsafe error).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create an account, you can, but I recommend this for experienced Linux user.

```
user=user
password=`openssl passwd -1 -salt xyz your-password-here`

cp /etc/passwd /tmp/passwd.bak

echo "${user}:${password}:1000:1000:User,,,:/tmp/${user}:/bin/sh" >> /etc/passwd
mkdir /tmp/${user}
chmod 1000:1000 /tmp/user
```

Don't log out existing session and test separately if you are able to SSH with your new account and root. This is to not lose access forever if you did a mistake in `/etc/passwd`.

So now you have read-only account.

---

Situation is limited now, because (at least) on my router there is no `su` or `sudo` binaries.  So it's not easy to give access to what you want without compiling binaries.

---

If you don't want to compile, you can allow only a script via root (UID `0`) and session will be closed:

```
echo "${user}:${password}:0:0:User,,,:/tmp/${user}:/tmp/script.sh" >> /etc/passwd
echo '#!/bin/sh
echo hello' >> /tmp/script.sh
chmod +x /tmp/script.sh
```